# How to view wlan encryption mode on a Mac?

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, encryption

I currently use Mac OS X Snow Leopard on a MacBook. I'd like to view the encryption mode that a wireless network is using. I.e. something like network X is using WPA with AES. Is this possible or do I need some third party software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's sufficient detailed for you: pressing Option while clicking the AirPort icon in the menu bar displays more details for your current connection, *and* enables tooltips for all other networks in that list.

Comment: +1. I never cease to be amazed at what little treasures the Option key can uncover!